# Multi user full disk encryption - larger than 8 user threshold. i.e. Not luks

Tags: linux, encryption, luks, multiple-users

I know Luks has a maximum of 8 I need something that does what LUKS does but allows multiple keys more than the maximum of 8.

All users will need to be able to access root.
It will be used regularly by multiple different users but not simultaneously.

I have looked at loads of different encryption tools but they do not seem to have any multi user system that does what I need, unless I've glossed over something.

Comment: There are probably some alternative to having lots of full disk encryption passwords, but you'll need to provide more details about your use case.

Comment: If all users can access root, it's sufficient for any such user to know *one* password only as such user can change any LUKS password. So what are you other users protecting from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LUKS full dsk encryption passwords are separate from user account passwords. So you can create as many users on the system as you like. But anyone who needs to boot the system will need to know one of the LUKS passwords. I'm not aware of any full disk encryption solutions for Linux that will let you have lots of passwords.

So if you need full disk encryption, you'll need to set up one password for LUKS that users share. Each use can then have their own login password once the system boots.

Depending on your exact situation, you might want to use home directory encryption instead of or in addition to full disk encryption. This would allow each user's home directory to be encrypted with their own password. But be aware that users will be able to use root access to access each other's encrypted files.

Comment: Yeah I thought about this just last night, didn't realise Luks and the linux os logins were seperate, cheers Satwell